# The 'library' tag is hidden on the Stack Apps website

Tags: feature-request, stackapps

I am using the Stack Exchange API in my application. While browsing through the website I found that the `library` tag is not present on the website, so that people can directly click on it. Also, we don't have [Meta Stack Apps](http://meta.stackapps.com/), because of which I have to ask the question here. Here are the snapshots posted for reference.

First screenshot: (no "library" link)

> [image]

Also, in this screenshot, clicking on the link marked doesn't give posts tagged as `script`. It gives posts tagged as `app` or `library` only:

> [image]

The desired result should be giving posted tagged as `app` or `library` or `script`.

[This is another link for reference](https://stackapps.com/q/7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. The [library](/questions/tagged/library) is missing from the header. It is integrated with the [apps](/questions/tagged/apps) tab.

It is a little confusing though: the [first page](https://stackapps.com/) doesn't show as much libraries as it does when you click *Browse the complete list*. You do see the third item is a library on that page and it doesn't come forward on the front page. I wouldn't consider this a bug, just another sorting algorithm used. Not a big deal.

There is no problem by-the-way posting your questions about StackApps here. Meta Stack Exchange is the meta for StackApps too.

Comment: I have edited the description about the second screenshot. Clicking on the link marked in the second screenshot doesn't give posts tagged as `script`. It gives posts tagged as `app` or `library` only.

Comment: True. There is a separate tab for [tag:script].

Comment: The desired result should be giving posted tagged as `app` or `library` or `script`.

Comment: Not sure if I agree. The current behavior isn't very clear though. Maybe edit the header?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you expect a tag to appear there.

To reach a tag page, you need to click the tag. Direct link: https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library

> [image]

Comment: The problem that I stated was about consistency in the website.

Comment: @Sha it is present on the frontpage too. Apps and libraries are combined in that view.

Comment: @Pat I don't really understand, still - it's just a tag like C# on Stack Overflow so there's no place for all tags in that menu.

Comment: Indeed, but there are three main tags. Only two are shown. That seems inconsistent. (Although I don't mind myself)

Comment: @Pat you mean like "bug", "feature-request", "support", "discussion" here on MSE? If so, here too only two of those are present in the top links menu.

Comment: @Sha I don't see those as tabs here, like on SA.

Comment: @Pat http://i.stack.imgur.com/nCFjt.png - only bugs and reqs (feature requests)

Comment: Oh man, I hate the new nav... http://i.imgur.com/sDaUy1C.png

Comment: That would make the rule clear: there are just two. Period. The two most important are shown.

Comment: All are equally important.

Comment: @amit but there's no room for all, it's a technical design matter.